# Proving '$A$ open in $V\subseteq M$ (metric space) iff $A=C\cap V$ (certain open $C$ in $M$)'

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I want to prove the following:

> Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Let $A\subseteq V\subseteq M$.
>
> 1) $A$ is open in $V \Leftrightarrow A = C\cap V$ (for a certain open $C$ in $M$)
>
> 2) $A$ is closed in $V \Leftrightarrow A = C\cap V$ (for a certain closed $C$ in $M$)

#### Questions:

- Could someone check the proof?
- '*for a certain open $C$ in $\color{Blue}{M}$.*'

  Would this proof also work for a more specific choice of $C$? 
  Like for a certain open $C$ in $\color{blue}{V}$. I don't really see the added value of choosing $M$ over $V$.
- Could some give me some pointers on how to prove $2, \Rightarrow$?

#### Proof 1)

$\Leftarrow$: Choose $a\in A$.

$$\begin{array}{rl}
& a \in A = C\cap V\\
\Rightarrow & a \in C\\
\Rightarrow & (\exists r > 0)(B_M(a,r)\subseteq C)\\
\Rightarrow & (\exists r > 0)(B_M(a,r)\cap V \subseteq C\cap V)\\
\Rightarrow & (\exists r> 0) (B_V(a,r)\subseteq A
\end{array}$$

$\Rightarrow$: Choose $a\in A$.

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\Rightarrow & (\exists r_a >0)(B_V(a,r_a) \subseteq A)
\end{array}$$

Consider all $a\in A$ then:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
& A = \bigcup_{a\in A} B_V(a,r_a)\\
\Rightarrow &  A = \bigcup_{a\in A} \left[ V\cap B_M(a,r_a)\right]\\
\Rightarrow &  A = V\cap\left[ \bigcup_{a\in A} B_M(a,r_a)\right]
\end{array}$$

Let $$\left[ \bigcup_{a\in A} B_M(a,r_a)\right] = C$$ which is open as a union of open sets.

#### Proof 2)

$\Leftarrow$:

$$\begin{array}{rrl}
&  V\setminus A &= V\setminus(C\cap V)\\
\Rightarrow & & = (V\setminus C)\cup (V\setminus V)\\
\Rightarrow && = V\setminus C
\end{array}$$

Since $C$ is closed then $V\setminus C$ is open and so is $V\setminus A$. Then $A$ is closed in $V$.

$\Rightarrow$: How?

Answer (score 0):

So far everything seems right.  For the last proof, let $ A$ closed in $ V $. Then $ V\backslash A $ is open in $ V $. By the first statement (which you already proved) there exists an open $ B $ in $ M $ such that $ V\backslash A=B\cap V $. Now $ A=(M\backslash B)\cap V $. And we know that $C= M\backslash B$ is closed in $ M $ because $ B $ is open in $ M$.

Sidenote: For non-metric spaces, we actually define the induced topology (the most natural and conventional one) on a subset of a topological space like this.